# How to scroll images horizontally in windows phone 8 one by one?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, listbox, scrollviewer

Here piece of code.I can not see the images individually. The scroll goes for inertia

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" Grid.Row="1"  Width="480"    ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" Width="480"/>
         </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

but not work.
Help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the more OS like look and feel ( like how images are shown in the pictures lib ), take a look at the nuget called Windows Phone Media Viewer ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneMediaViewer/ ).

There is even a sample app where it's been used up on MSDN ( http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b )

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot control as parent and add images as pivot items, and you can swipe horizontally.

or you can
1) use stack panel as parent 
2)and add images inside a stack panel
3)set its orientation as horizontal 
4)use a horizontal scroll viewer as parent of stack panel.

hope this helps.
Thank you.

Comment: Do note that using a pivot, you'll need to keep track of memory usage! The mediaviewer class solution I'm suggesting is virtualized, so will not eat up all your memory when you add a lot of images.